# Doctrine throws Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got end of string." error

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

I have a db method called get_price(int, int, int) which calculates price of a product. 
I Also created GetPriceFunction class  and registered it in doctrine.yml

the class

```
class GetPriceFunction extends FunctionNode
{
public $firstExpression = null;
public $secondExpression = null;
public $thirdExpression = null;

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser
 */
public function parse(Parser $parser)
{
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
    $this->firstExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
    $this->secondExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
    $this->thirdExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker
 * @return int
 */
public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
{
    return 'get_price(' . $this->firstExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ',' . $this->secondExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ',' . $this->thirdExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ')';
}
}
```

doctrine.yml

```
numeric_functions:
            get_price: Shopsys\ShopBundle\Component\Doctrine\GetPriceFunction
```

when i call the method like this

```
$this->em->createQuery('get_price(1,1,1)')->execute();
```

i get this error

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got end of string."
```

What is causing this error and how can i fix this?

Comment: I believe createQuery expects, as its parameter, a dql query and not just some string. I might be wrong though

Comment: Jakumi is right. createQuery expects an SQL sintax. You may want to store the values from your function and then create a Query Binding the value of those parameters.